# The Method is undefined for the type object

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been researching this however I can't seem to correct the error. I have a "The Method is undefined for the type object" error on both `getStatusCode()` and `getReasonPhrase()`. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
My code is as follows

```
package com.javapapers.java.io;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class HttpUtil {

    public String getHttpResponse(HttpRequestBase request) {
        String result = null;
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String reason = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(reason);
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
        } catch (IOException ex2) {
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the compiler thinks getStatusLine() is returning an Object, not a StatusLine. Very weird...

Comment: You can press Ctrl and click on `getStatusLine()` to see it's implementation and what object is it returning to you.

Comment: What version of apache httpclient are you using?

Comment: I used org.apche.solrj.client.solrj_3.5.0.v20150506-0844.jar @azurefrog

Comment: Sorry if I sound condescending, but are you sure that's where you are getting those classes from?  That looks like a solr client jar, but the class/package names in your source code look like they're from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: @azurefrog you don't sound condescending I'm new at this so I'm clueless enough. I added an image to the question of my Apache files. I hope you can tell me if I'm using the correct ones or if it may have anything to do with my errors. Thanks

Comment: Huh, I can see you've got httpclient-4.5.1 in there, which is what I compiled your code against without any problem.  I'm a little suspicious that you have multiple versions of httpcore in your classpath, though. You'll notice that you've got httpcore-4.4.3 coming from httpcomponents-client-4.5.1-bin.tar, but you've also got httpcore-4.0.1.jar imported directly, and httpcore-4.4.4.jar from httpcomponents-core-4.4.4-bin.  I'd try cleaning out the duplication and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: It's hard to say that is the root issue here, though, since no version of httpcore returns `Object` from its `getStatusLine()` method... :p

Comment: @azurefrog which one would you suggest deleting